# While looping through data, multiple arrays are created instead of one

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning JS, and making an appointments project for learning.

Below after fetching and getting data from firebase, I'm storing the data in an array object so that I can sort the data based on dates, however when I'm displaying the data on the page it is showing multiple entries instead of 10 which is actually the total records in the database.

```
// Showing appointments of the current and previous month.
let startDateArr = []
let startMonthArr = []
let allRecords = []
let update = false

const showingApts = (doc) => {

  let newTime = new Date(doc.data().dateInMills.at(-1) * 1000)

  allRecords.push({
    id: doc.id,
    name: doc.data().aptName,
    slot: doc.data().aptTimeSlot,
    email: doc.data().aptEmail,
    day: doc.data().aptDay.at(-1),
    type: doc.data().aptType,
    date: doc.data().aptStartDate.at(-1),
    month: doc.data().aptStartMonth.at(-1),
    year: doc.data().aptStartYear.at(-1),
    status: doc.data().appointmentStatus,
    softDelete: doc.data().softDelete,
    time: newTime
  })

  allRecords.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.time - b.time
  })

  // Fetching names from profiles db.
  db.collection('profiles').onSnapshot((querySnapshotProfiles) => {
    querySnapshotProfiles.forEach((profileDoc) => {
      if (profileDoc.data().aptEmail.at(-1) === doc.data().aptEmail) {
        startDateArr.push(doc.data().aptStartDate.at(-1))
        startMonthArr.push(doc.data().aptStartMonth.at(-1))
      }
    })
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    let aptStartDate = startDateArr.at(-1)
    let aptStartMonth = startMonthArr.at(-1)

    if (doc.data().aptStartDate.at(-1) === aptStartDate && doc.data().aptStartMonth.at(-1) === aptStartMonth) {
      return update = true
    }

    for (let record of allRecords) {

      let currentMonthAppointments = `
    
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-center align-middle tableRow12">
                <div class="grid grid-cols-6 text-center py-4 place-items-center text-xs border-b border-gray-200  hover:bg-blue-100 ease-in-out duration-300 text-blue-600 font-semibold px-2" data-id="${ record.id }">
               
                <span>
                  <span class='scheduleName'>${ record.name } </span>
                  <span class='scheduleEmail block text-[10px] text-gray-400 font-medium'>${ record.email } </span>
                  <div class='text-center w-full mt-2 font-medium'><button class='addMoreApt ${ update === true ? 'inline' : 'hidden' } text-center rounded-md bg-rose-600 p-2 text-white cursor-pointer text-[10px] '>Add 5 more appointments</button></div>
                </span>
                <span>${ record.slot }</span>
                <span>
                  <span> ${ record.day }, </span>
                  <span>${ record.date }-${ record.month }-${ record.year } </span>
                </span>
                <span>${ record.type }</span>

              </div>
              </div>
    `
      scheduleTableRows.innerHTML += currentMonthAppointments
    }
  }, 1000)
}

// Clearing old rows in the table
const rowsToDelete = () => {
  let tableRowsToDelete = document.querySelectorAll('.tableRow12')
  for (let rowsToDelete of tableRowsToDelete) {
    rowsToDelete.remove()
  }
}
```

When I console.log(allRecords) I get ten arrays instead of one, and all the data is populated on the page when showed.

[image: All records]

Database structure

[image: Db1]

Profile section

[image: Db2]

Comment: can you provide the structure of your collection so we can recreate it to solve the issue ? Without that we would not get any context regarding the issue

Comment: that does not show all the fields in the collection like where is aptMonth and profiles collection ?

Comment: check now, I have updated the question.

Comment: From the first look of it your `showingApts` functions is called multiple times and hence the records were pushed to the `allrecords` multiple times. You can use `allRecords = []` at the beginning of `showingApts` function. And place setTimeout ouside the `showingApts` function. And why are you using arrays to store singular string values ?

Comment: yes because it's coming from a different script where its looping values from Db. The reason setTimeout is inside is because the emails that are cross checked are populated by another db calls and it takes a while to get the list, if I place it outside the list won't show. Arrays are used as those values with time will get updated, so just to store all the changes using an array.

Comment: Have you tried the above suggested changes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251545/discussion-between-alittlehotcurry-and-rohit-kharche).